# Apache: Log messages from CGI to own file

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, cgi

I would like to have all the output from the (perl) CGIs in its own log file.

What i tried:

Setting `ScriptLog /var/log/httpd/cgi.log` in `httpd.conf`, but this had no effect. Probably something else is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your understanding of what ScriptLog does and the [official documentation on ScriptLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html#scriptlog) seem to be at odds.

Comment: `The ScriptLog directive sets the CGI script error logfile`: This sounds exactly what i want to do. Just that nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptLog only logs errors. You can use comparison values at the end of the CustomLog statement to output specific events into another log. I think something like this will do what you want (tested):

```
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/cgi-bin/" cgilog
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!cgilog
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cgi.log combined env=cgilog
```

Comment: This does the acesslog part of the CGIs into its own file. It would be nice to have the error.log there too

Comment: True, but I don't think there is a way to do that for general errors. Errors from the CGI stderr output will go to the ScriptLog file so you could combine those.